# Debugging and preprocessor directive

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor

For debugging I have many calls to a debug log function in my application. Of course in the production version these debugging calls need to be skipped. Instead of writing:

```
#if DEVEL == 1
    Log::debug(...);
#endif
```

around all calls to the debug function I decided the write the following in the debug function itself:

```
#if DEVEL != 1
    return;
#endif
```

Will the overhead of the useless function call be avoided by the compiler or am I better off by using (many ugly) `#if #endif` construction for performance reasons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of worrying about optimizer, you can do a simple trick:

```
#if DEVEL == 1
#define LOG_DEBUG(...) Log::Debug(__VA_ARGS__)  // variadic macro
#else
#define LOG_DEBUG
#endif
```

Now use `LOG_DEBUG` everywhere to keep it simple.

Comment: Nice. Why doesn't the #else version take parameters, though?

Comment: @Kerrek, because there are only 2 conditions. If it's not `DEVEL == 1` then it will be surely `DEVEL != 1`.

Comment: No sorry, what I meant is why does the first version of LOG_DEBUG have arguments (parentheses), but the second doesn't? If you write `LOG_DEBUG("hello")`, then the second macro would expand to `"hello"`, not nothing, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, in the second case LOG_DEBUG will be replaced by nothing, regardless of arguments.

Answer (score 5):

If the function is available for inlining (e.g. it is implemented in the header) then the optimizer will have no trouble getting rid of the function call and thus leave you with no overhead.

Comment: Even if it's not defined in the header file the call will most likely be removed by link-time optimizations.

Comment: Better to be removed at compile time, so the call doesn't impact register allocation or prolog/epilog for a leaf versus non-leaf caller function

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you check?

With gcc just compile with `-S`, and look at the output.

Comment: and turn on the optimizer: -O or -O3